# Embedding a Tomcat server on CD-ROM (or unwritable disk)

Tags: tomcat, cd-rom

Suppose I need to make a CDROM with a Tomcat server. How can I guarantee that all the jsp files have correctly been compiled before I build the CD image to be burnt ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat uses Jasper for JSP management, there's some guidance in the [documention](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jasper-howto.html) on precompiling JSPs. Once the server has been started up once, you can copy the directories to the target disk.

Alternatively, Ant has a (deprecated) [JSP compilation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jspc.html) task.

Update: There's a [blog](http://firstclassthoughts.co.uk/ant/jsp_compile.html) that describes how to use Ant to compile your JSPs.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [this link.](http://www.dekoh.org/wiki/view/HowToPrecompileJspFiles)  It describes how to pre compile your JSP files in ANT or Maven.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did,

1. Precompile all your JSPs.
2. Run all your WARs unexploded.
3. Test your server and make sure nothing is created in webapps and work directory.

I was amazed so many libraries we use assume that the WAR is exploded and try to read files in WEB-INF.